# Parts of top bar are vertically offset

Tags: gnome, panel, 20.04, top-bar

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 (GNOME desktop) and parts of the top bar are vertically offset, appearing outside the bar. As a result it overlaps with my open windows and I find it frustrating. Is there anyway to fix this issue? The top bar was fine when I was using Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: top bar misaligned]

Comment: can you please upload a screenshot of your issue?  imgur is a good platform to upload and link an image here.  Also, please confirm the flavor of Ubuntu you are using (Are you using the default GNOME?)  Have you now, or ever, tweaked with the appearance of your desktop outside of the included system settings?  For example, installing software for "themes" or otherwise manually manipulating files related to the desktop environment?  Reversing these changes may help.

Comment: @Nmath I am using the GNOME that ships with Ubuntu. I had installed GNOME Tweaks when I had Ubuntu 18.04 (which I was using until recently). Here's a link to the screenshot https://imgur.com/3BFfKPI.png

Comment: It definitely looks like a config issue.  (something that was altered in the past that doesn't play nice with the new) I suggest completely uninstalling and removing all files associated with GNOME Tweak Tool and also suggest going through your ~/.config folder for all applications associated with the appearance of the desktop (like gtk).  You can back up these config files/folders by changing file names, such as adding `bak` to the end of the file name.  Config files in these folders are generally set up to automatically create a new file with the default settings when they are absent.

Comment: you also have a few 3rd party applications that have added icons on the top panel, it could also be the case that a 3rd party application's icon is too big/small or otherwise misconfigured.  See if those apps will allow you to disable the system tray / panel icons.

Comment: @Nmath thank you for your suggestions. I seemed to have fixed the issue simply by changing the theme. I appreciate you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue due to some extension that you might possibly have installed. If this is not the case, then you might consider reporting it to the ubuntu forum so, that it can be fixed in the pointer release of ubuntu 20.04.

Until then you can use [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension to get rid of the top bar and get a taskbar instead.

UPDATE:

Try changing the shell theme. You might need [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the issue was with an icon theme which was not compatable with Ubuntu 20.04. After I changed it the top bar was back to normal

Comment: You never mentioned that you changed icon theme. Anyways, good luck!